# Django: Views within views

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

This may seem very basic, but, though I can guess, how do you make a view within a view, or more accurately, a dynamic template within a dynamic template. You see, I have these blocks of html which contain stats on certain things. How would I create a view that returned one of these boxes so another view could insert them into a template block? Is it "ok" to just have a function which returns it, or do I "have to" follow the same `functionName(request)` thing instead of `functionName(info1, info2, info3)` like a normal function. This seems like such a common thing that there would be some sort of standard.

Comment: Look into custom template tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you're basically talking about pre-populating the template context. Basically, you want a common bit of context to be present in a number of views, but you don't want to repeat yourself for each view. Using function-based views, the best way is to simply have generic method that takes care of this:

```
def add_some_context(context={}):
    context['foo'] = 'bar'
    return context

def view1(self, request):
    context = {
        'something1': 'blah',
    }
    return render_to_response('template1.html', add_some_context(context), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def view2(self, request):
    context = {
        'something2': 'blah',
    }
    return render_to_response('template2.html', add_some_context(context), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Both views will have a `foo` context variable you can use, then. Doing it with class-based views, you can create a mixin class:

```
class MyViewMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyViewMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['foo'] = 'bar'
        return context

class MyView1(MyViewMixin, DetailView):
    ...

class MyView2(MyViewMixin, ListView):
    ...
```

When it comes time to add this to the actual template, you can have each view's template inherit from a template that implements the `foo` context variable in some way.

If it's something that should be applied to *every* view, then a context processor is more appropriate, but if it's just for a handful of views, then these two methods will serve you well.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/) - in particular inclusion tags - are for.